# Windows Server 2008 dns / ADWS every ~7 day of running

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have a HP Server with Windows Server 2008 installed and have been running for about 5 years without errors.

Last half year I have encountered error in the event viewer every day and after 7 days of running the server can no longer access simple things like "Active Directory Users And Computers" there will be an error when I open it. (something like cannot determine global catalogue server)
Neither browsing the internet will work or connecting to the local nas or router / 192.168.0.1
A simple restart give me about another 7 days before the error appears.

I frequently receive errors (4500 errors a week) with event id 1206 ADWS (Active Directory Web Services was unable to determine if the computer is a global catalog server.)

No huge differences have been made to the server, no anti virus are currently installed. Windows firewall is off.
No other servers or AD in the network.

```
  (dcdiag /v) gives this error
  Running enterprise tests on : "server name"
  Test omitted by user request: DNS
  Test omitted by user request: DNS
  Starting test: LocatorCheck
     GC Name: \\"server name"
     Locator Flags: 0xe00031bd
     PDC Name: \\Server name"
     Locator Flags: 0xe00031bd
     Warning: DcGetDcName(TIME_SERVER) call failed, error 1355
     A Time Server could not be located.
     The server holding the PDC role is down.
     Warning: DcGetDcName(GOOD_TIME_SERVER_PREFERRED) call failed, error
     1355
     A Good Time Server could not be located.
     KDC Name: \\"Server name"
     Locator Flags: 0xe00031bd
     ......................... "Server name" failed test
     LocatorCheck
  Starting test: Intersite
     Skipping site Default-First-Site-Name, this site is outside the scope
     provided by the command line arguments provided.
     ......................... "Server name" passed test Intersite
```

Thanks for any help and sorry for my non native English.

Comment: Why are you skipping the DNS test? This sounds like a possible DNS problem. What does the server use for DNS?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment!
Did I skip the DNS test?
The server currently uses 127.0.0.1 as preferred
and alternative 8.8.8.8

Comment: Stop using 8.8.8.8. From what I gather about the server it is a Domain Controller, yes? A Domain Controller (when it also has the DNS role installed) should point to it's partner DC/DNS server for primary DNS (if it has a partner DC/DNS server), should point to itself for secondary DNS and should point to 127.0.0.1 for tertiary DNS. If it has no partner DC/DNS server then it should point to itself for primary DNS and to 127.0.0.1 for secondary DNS. At no time should it use **ANY** other DNS server(s).

Comment: Yes that's true it is an Domain Controller and also acting as an DNS server.
Hum, I never thought of that ill absolutely give that a try!
Thanks a lot for the help!